# Why worker nodes of WSO2 DSS do not checked out deployments automatically

Tags: cluster-computing, wso2-data-services-server

I've configured DSS cluster according this tutorial: http://bytefeeder.blogspot.ru/2014/05/creating-wso2-dss-cluster-with-shared.html

As part of this configuration I've setup Deployment Synhronization via svn.

My worker nodes has configured it via carbon.xml:

```
    <DeploymentSynchronizer>
       <Enabled>true</Enabled>
       <AutoCommit>false</AutoCommit>
       <AutoCheckout>true</AutoCheckout>
       <RepositoryType>svn</RepositoryType>
       <SvnUrl>file:///home/akakunin/work/wso2/wso2dss_cluster/svnrepo</SvnUrl>
       <SvnUser>repouser</SvnUser>
       <SvnPassword>repopassword</SvnPassword>
       <SvnUrlAppendTenantId>true</SvnUrlAppendTenantId>
    </DeploymentSynchronizer>
```

Now, I'm testing how it work. I've logged in into Management Console of Management Node and create new server.
I can see - server was deployed into Management node and commited into svn repo.
But both worker nodes to not want to checkout this deployment automatically.

But - if I restart one working node - during startup it succesfully checkout service and deployed it.

So - in generally - Deployment Synhronized working - after restart I've get service on working node - but why it is not working at runtime - just after service is deployed into management node?

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason for this - clustering was not configured correctly - worker nodes was not connected to cluster - so, they did not received commands from master to perform updates.
After proper configuration of clustering in worker nodes service was deployed into worker nodes as soon as they was created in management node.